# How to clear a specific layer (fusion layer) - google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Here's the following problem:

I'm importing a fusion layer, which is queried by a list, works fine.
However, when I change the query, instead of just displaying the new results, it also displays the previous ones. I've tried different approaches, but none seems to work.

I would really be greatful for some insight

Comment: What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please show the code you use to make/change queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
yourLayer.setMap(null);
```

to clear the map.

you can refer to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44etgjrx/) for clearing the traffic layer as reference.